# Turn this cmdlet into a script: Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Einar\Desktop\log\* -filter *1234567.log.txt | Select -First 2 | Select -last 1

Tags: powershell

Basically, I want to input 7 digits and get second line in the log file as an output.

This is my first time attempting anything in powershell btw

Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Einar\Desktop\log* -filter ***1234567**.log.txt | Select -First 2 | Select -last 1

I have a folder with log files, that all end with (random7digits).log.txt, and I want to output only the second line by inputting a set of 7 digits.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: As an aside: `Select -First 2 | Select -last 1` can be simplified as `Select -Index 1` (or `Select -Skip 1 -First 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very basic form, this achieves what you want. You can save this is a .ps1 and save it on your desktop. If you right click and `Run with PowerShell`, then the console will close after immediately returning. Either call the script from a pre-existing console session, or add a `pause` or something at the end.

I recommend you expand upon it as a learning exercise with some of these ideas:

- Check whether the file exists and provide sensible error handling or message to the user
- Check if the file contains your 'ideal' content, or even two lines at all, and provide sensible error handling or message to the user
- Perhaps add another parameter, with a default value to your desktop, in case you ever need to run it with logs elsewhere on disk

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [int]$Digit
)
Get-ChildItem -Path <path_containing_files> -File -Filter *$Digit.log.txt | ForEach-Object { 
  Get-Content -Path $_ | Select-Object -Index 1 
}
```

Comment: Didn't work at first, but I noticed that there was a missing "\" behind \log
But it doesn't filter out the specific line i want

Comment: I removed the `-Raw` parameter from `Get-Content`, see my revision. It would help if you provided some example data and example desired result if it continues to 'not work' for you.

Comment: Here is some sample data, sorry
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jbcB6ZsnxmHjqEfFNeqNx22fUoN1EoUH?usp=sharing

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, there might be multiple log files that end with the same 7 digit number, I want to retrieve the second line in all the files that opens.

Comment: My latest revision works for me with the data you provided.

Comment: Hm, I'm not getting any output anymore (I added the path)

Comment: The path you entered is probably wrong.

Comment: Hm, looks like I have the right path:
https://imgur.com/do8F4uL
https://imgur.com/FrpzzcJ

Comment: No, your path is wrong. Remove the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

### function Get-Logline

```
function Get-Loglines{      
   param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, HelpMessage='Enter Path to Log Folder:' )]
    [string]$Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, HelpMessage='Enter string to filter for: *(string).log.txt')]
    [int]$filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, HelpMessage='Enter line number to read back:')]
    [int]$linenumber
    )

  process{
      $lookdepth = $linenumber - 1
      Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Filter ('*{0}.log.txt' -f $filename) -force -Verbose |`
      
      ForEach-Object{
       Get-Content $_ -Verbose |`
       Select-Object -Skip $lookdepth -First 1 -Verbose
  }
 }
}
```

### Test Case

```
C:\> Get-Loglines
cmdlet Get-Loglines at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Path: C:\Downloads\Newfolder
filename: 666666
linenumber: 2
line 2
```

## Example Data

```
C:\Downloads\Newfolder [master +39 ~0 -0 !]> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: C:\Downloads\Newfolder


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                          
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                          
-a----         4/21/2022   2:37 PM             38 ab123456.log.txt                                                                                                                                              
-a----         4/21/2022   2:37 PM             38 ab666666.log.txt                                                                                                                                              
-a----         4/21/2022   2:37 PM             38 ab666667.log.txt                                                                                                                                              
-a----         4/21/2022   2:37 PM             38 acb666666.log.txt  


C:\Downloads\Newfolder> Get-Content .\ab666666.log.txt 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```